# Ошибка в переборе массива в цикле for

Tags: c++, массивы

Функция:

```
extern int FeedForward(int inputs[])
{
    for (int x : inputs.begin())
//Ошибка здесь   ^^^^^^
    {}
}
```

Выдает ошибку:
E0153   выражение должно иметь тип класса
Почему так?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Потому что оператор `.` в языке С++ применим только к классам, разумеется. Что вы хотели сказать этим `begin()`? У указателя нет никакого `begin()`.

Comment: @AnT я просто недавно начал изучат, поэтому еще не до конца разбираюсь...

Comment: Но вы ведь написали это не путем случайного долбления по клавишам, так? Вы чего-то ожидали, опирались на какую-то логику?

Comment: @AnT Подозрение о переходе откуда-нибудь с Java, например...

Comment: @NeulovimFox, это range-based for. Не трогай его пока, раз ты даже классы толком не изучил.

Comment: @AnT не угадали, с C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не сработает. Не сработает потому, что у вас `int inputs[]` превращается в указатель, а это С++, и никакого `.begin()` у указателя не предусмотрено, и внутри функции вы ничего не знаете о том, на какое количество элементов он указывает...

```
int FeedForward(int inputs[], int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int x = inputs[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

Можно - если вы будете передавать в функцию *именно массив* - воспользоваться шаблонами, типа

```
template<int N>
int FeedForward(int (&inputs)[N])
{
    for(int x: inputs)
    {}
}

...

int a[5];
FeedForward(a);
```

Comment: я бы просил добавит в Ваш ответ, что желательно бы обернуть массив в контейнер, vector к примеру.

Comment: @Andrey Почему - желательно обернуть? Просто - лучше пользоваться векторами, чем обычными массивами. Или `array`.

Comment: Ну тут у человека уже с-стайл массив, его оборачивать. В новых местах да, использовать stl

Comment: Да и вообще для таких вещей есть gsl::span